# How to set search term and post back to page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a number of tags that when clicked should set the new search term and do a post back to the same page I'm on.

So I need to set the new search term.
And do a refresh or post back to my page im on.

Index.cshtml

```
 <div class="col-sm-10">
        @foreach (String tag in Model.MySearchResults[i].Tags)
        {
            <span class="badge" >
                <a href="~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml" >
                    @tag
                    @Model.SearchTerm = @Model.MySearchResults[i].Tags.ToString()
                </a>

            </span>
        }
    </div>
```

Just learning C# mvc 3rd week into training. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: what about the Action in your controller, does it accept a SearchTerm argument ? anything else ? could you edit your question with the signature of the action which will consume the SearchTerm parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually depends on the action behind your Index view.

Typically, it would accept a single string argument, `searchTerm`.

If this is the case, you can edit your HTML accordingly:

```
<a href="~/Views/Home?SearchTerm=@Model.MySearchResults[i].Tags.ToString()">
```

If you need to pass other values, you might have to add other parameters to the queryString.